# cookie.setMaxAge(-1) is not working on Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, servlets, cookies

I am sending a response and setting a maxAge for cookie as -1.All browsers except Chrome delete my cookie once browser is closed.

Chrome browser shows - [image]

But still cookie does not get deleted when I close the browser.How to delete a cookie on chrome?Or is there any robust way which will work on all the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Likely to be one of these problems:

1. Chrome is still running in the background even though you closed the browser, so the session did not clear up.
2. One of the many bugs[1] relating to session cookie deletion problem in chrome.

   [1] https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-bugs/session$20cookies$20not$20deleted

As per spec, not setting `max-age` and `expires` directives causes browsers to treat your cookie as a `session` cookie.   `cookie.setMaxAge(-1)` is doing the right thing internally if you say it works on all other browsers except chrome, though you can try setting a cookie without `max-age` and `expires` i.e., to have your http header field like this:

```
Set-Cookie: test=2015; Path=/; Domain=.example.
```

I believe the robust solution is to go by the spec. Do not bother about setting `expires` and `max-age` values, if you'd want a strict session cookie. We, then, leave it upto the browsers to respect the spec.